# What's the meaning of shifting in fixed-point arithmetic when implementing it in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, fixed-point

I have a problem with understanding fixed-point arithmetic and its implementation in C++. I was trying to understand this code:

```
#define scale 16

int DoubleToFixed(double num){
    return num * ((double)(1 << scale));
}

double FixedToDoble(int num){
    return (double) num / (double)(1 << scale);
}

double IntToFixed(int num){
    return x << scale
}
```

I am trying to understand exactly why we shift. I know that shifting to the right is basically multiplying that number by 2<sup>x</sup>, where x is by how many positions we want to shift or scale, and shifting to the left is basically division by 2<sup>x</sup>.

But why do we need to shift when we convert from int to fixed point?

Comment: c/c++ isn't a thing. Pick a language (these are different), and provide a [mcve] regarding your concern as absolutely required here.

Comment: `1 << scale` for that value of `scale` does nasty things on a system with a 16 bit `int`. The author needs a good talking to. Just write 65536, or 0x10000, pretty please with sugar on top.

Comment: Fixed-point arithmetic typically involves multiplying and dividing by a *scale factor*.  Theoretically the scale factor can be anything, although typically it is either a power of 10 or a power of two.  `1<<x` is a quick way to compute a power of 2.  So in this example, `scale` is interpreted as a number of bits, and the actual scale factor multiplied or divided by is `1<<scale`, which is 2 raised to the power of `scale`, or 2¹⁶, or 65536.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i just mentioned that i am implementing it on c/c++, i just want to understand the idea of shifting bits in fixed point arithmetic,.......thanks

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i am saying that the implementation is the same, in c or c++...thanks

Comment: Careful with that assumption. I've seen some very poorly chosen operator overloads in C++ code.

Comment: @user4581301 and as a shifting operator in this meaning

Comment: Just to hammer home what the answers and some of the other comments are suggesting, the shift itself is not important to fixed point. It is just a means to an end, producing a multiplier. The number produced by the shift is what is important.

Comment: If it is any help, I'm making a programming language called **C/C++**, which is based on **OCaml**.  I haven't released it yet, but I can assure you the above code is not **C/C++** compliant.  That code looks more like **C** code.

Comment: @Eljay you can try it, anyway thank you,

Comment: Pendantic:  Shifting right is division, shifting left is multiplication.  Your understanding is not correct.  Shifing left:  `1 << 5`, shifting right: `5 >> 2`;.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: A minimal reproducible example is needed for debugging questions, not for questions like this one about what a particular piece of code does. It is not “absolutely required.”

Comment: Imagine you have the fixed point number `456` and it represents `4.56`.  You'll need to pack `4.56` into `456` (that's like what `DoubleToFixed` does).  And to use it, you'll need to unpack the `456` into `4.56` (that's like what `FixedToDoble` does).

Comment: Please take a look  at [ldexp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ldexp.3.html) for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

A fixed-point format represents a number as an integer multiplied by a fixed scale. Commonly the scale is some base *b* raised to some power *e*, so the integer *f* would represent the number *f*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>.

In the code shown, the scale is 2<sup>−16</sup> or 1/65,536. (Calling the the shift amount `scale` is a misnomer; 16, or rather −16, is the exponent.) So if the integer representing the number is 81,920, the value represented is 81,920•2<sup>−16</sup> = 1.25.

The routine `DoubleToFixed` converts a floating-point number to this fixed-point format by multiplying by the reciprocal of the scale; it multiplies by 65,536.

The routine `FixedToDouble` converts a number from this fixed-format to floating-point by multiplying by the scale or, equivalently, by dividing by its reciprocal; it divides by 65,536.

`IntToFixed` does the same thing as `DoubleToFixed` except for an `int` input.

Comment: A thorough chap such as your good self might want to point out the pitfalls of writing `1 << 16`. To me it fits into the `unsigned n = -1e1;` category of poor things to do.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil what I don't understand exactly is why we even need to scale in the first place even to convert a normal integer value to a fixed-point

Comment: @th3plus: In the fixed-point format, , the number is being used to represent a scaled value. If had some integer, say 32,768, and stored it in the format without adjusting it, then 32,768 would represent 32,768/65,536 = ½. Remember, even if the data for the format is stored as an integer type, it is not being used as an integer. It **represents** a different number, one that is scaled from the stored integer. When putting a value into the format, you must adjust it for this scaling.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of what the bits represent in terms of *place value*.  So for an 32 bit signed `int`, the place values are:

-2<sup>31</sup>,2<sup>30</sup>,2<sup>28</sup>, ... ,2<sup>2</sup>,2<sup>1</sup>,2<sup>0</sup>

while for a 16Q16 ([*ARM variant Q notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format))) 32 bit fixed point representation, the place values are *shifted* by 16 bits:

-2<sup>15</sup>,2<sup>14</sup>,2<sup>13</sup>, ... 2<sup>1</sup>,2<sup>0</sup>,2<sup>-1</sup>, ... ,2<sup>-15</sup>,2<sup>-16</sup>

So in conversion from integer or floating point values, you must multiply by 2<sup>16</sup>, and to convert from fixed, you must divide by 2<sup>16</sup>.

Worth noting that a plain 32-bit `int` is the same as a 32Q0 fixed point representation (i.e. 32 integer bits, zero fractional bits).

16Q16 gives a resolution of 2<sup>-16</sup> which is good for about 4 decimal places of precision [|*log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>-16</sup>)*| = *4.8*].  Moving the fixed point gives more or less precision, but affects the range, so it is easy to get an overflow with fixed point arithmetic.

There is more to it than just shifting for conversions of course.  For example while addition and subtraction are the same as the integer operations, after a multiply, it is necessary to divide by 2<sup>16</sup>, and for divide, you need to multiply the dividend (left-operand) by 2<sup>16</sup> before dividing by the divisor (right-operand). These operations require a larger intermediate type to avoid overflow.  Then implementation higher level math functions such as sin, cos, log is a whole different level of complexity.

It may be clearer with a *decimal* fixed point example (fixed-point is not usually implemented this way for general arithmetic for efficiency reasons, but it is useful in some specific applications - for example you might perform integer metric dimension calculations in centimetre units to get sufficient resolution without having to use floating point operations):

So let's say for example we have a decimal-fixed-point type, having two decimal places of precision, such that 1234 represents 12.34 (that is to say the `_unit value_` represents 0.01).  So to convert from fixed to integer, you must *divide* by 10<sup>2</sup> (100): `1234 / 100 == 12` (just as `(int)12.34 == 12`).

Similarly if I wanted to convert `12.34` to the decimal-2 fixed notation: `(int)(12.34 * 100) == 1234`.

Then for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division:

```c
1234 + 50 == 1284          // 12.34 + 0.50 == 12.84
1234 - 50 == 1184          // 12.34 - 0.50 == 11.84
(1234 * 50) / 100 == 617   // 12.34 * 0.50 == 6.17
(1234 * 100) / 50 == 2468  // 12.34 / 0.50 == 24.68
```

If you are going to use fixed point in C++ (and it is probably only justified for MCUs with no FPU), then I strongly suggest that you use a library such as that by Anthony Williams presented in his article [*Optimizing Math-intensive Applications with Fixed Point Arithmetic*](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html) rather than your somewhat naive example. The Dr.Dobb's article link itself seems to be broken, (can't get past the first page) which is  a shame - it may be available from other sources.  It would largely answer your question and much besides.  The source download still works.

Anyhow, Anthony Williams' library uses a more useful 36Q28 format (about 8 decimal places and +/-235 range), and implements a class `fixed` with extensive operator overloading and a more or less complete math library (trig functions, log etc.) such that you can largely simply replace `double` or `float` in your code with `fixed` and it will syntactically work pretty much like a built-in type - even implementing implicit conversions, so for example `fixed x = 2.5 ;` will work as expected without having to explicitly call a `DoubleToFixed()` conversion.  Compared to soft floating-point used on targets without an FPU it is in the order of 5 times faster on ARM.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed point arithmatic works on the concept of representing numbers as an integer multiple of a very small "base". Your case uses a base of `1/(1<<scale)`, aka `1/65536`, which is approximately `0.00001525878`.

So the number 3.141592653589793, could be represented as 205887.416146 units of `1/65536`, and so would be stored in memory as the integer value 205887 (which is really 3.14158630371, due to the rounding during conversion).

The way to calculate this conversion of fractional-value-to-fixed-point is simply to divide the value by the base: `3.141592653589793 / (1/65536) = 205887.416146`. (Notably, this reduces to `3.141592653589793  * 65536 = 205887.416146`). However, since this involves a power-of-two, this is the same as simply left shifting by that many bits. So multiplication of `2^16`, aka `65536`, can be calculated faster by simply shifting left `16` bits. This is *really* fast, which is why most fixed-point calculations use an negative-power-of-two as their base.

Due to the inability to shift `float` values, your methods convert the base to a `float` and does floating point multiplication, but other methods, such as the fixed-point multiplication and division themselves would be able to take advantage of this shortcut.

Theoretically, one *can* use shifting bits with floats to do the conversion functions faster than simply floating point multiplication, but most likely, the compiler is actually already doing that under the covers.

It is also common for some code to use an negative-power-of-ten as their base, primarily for money, which usually uses a base of `0.01`, but these cannot use a single shift as a shortcut, and have to do slower math. One shortcut for multiplying by 100 is `value<<6 + value<<5 + value<<2` (this is effectively `value*64+value*32+value*4`, which is `value*(64+32+4)`, which is `value*100`), but three shifts and three adds is sometimes faster than one multiplication. Compilers already do this shortcut under the covers if 100 is a compile time constant, so in general, nobody writes code like this anymore.

Comment: Re “Multiplication by a power-of-two is the same as simply left shifting by that many bits”: `DoubleToFixed` and `FixedToDouble` perform floating-point multiplications or divisions. The multiplication or division is not the same as shifting.

Comment: Ah, yes, my explanation is math based, which, if translated directly to processors, would require an `operator*(float, int)`. The lack of such an operation doesn't invalidate my math, it merely means the conversion operations can't take direct advantage of the shifting. I'll note that explicitly.

Comment: I know what you mean by "_inverse-power-of-ten_", but that is simply a power of ten, 1/100 is 10 ^-2.  The "inverse" part is not necessary - the exponent is simply negative.

Comment: @Clifford: You're right. I switched this to "negative-power-of-ten"